# MySQL MATCH AGAINST functionality

Tags: mysql, match

Currently I have the following query...

```
SELECT id, 
       LOWER(title) as title, 
       LOWER(sub_title) as sub_title
  FROM ebay_archive_listing
 WHERE MATCH(title, sub_title) AGAINST ("key" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However it is not finding rows where the `title` contains the word "key".  "key" is generated dynamically based on a  set of keywords, so sometimes it contains + and - symbols.

Comment: have you tried it while removing the LOWER functions? I don't know if that is messing with it or not. Also, try a few other words. See if you can find a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's default fulltext indexing settings won't index or match any word of fewer than four letters.

If you have a phrase made entirely of words of fewer than four letters like `key` you have to manually fall back to an unindexed `LIKE` search instead.

You can change this behaviour by [lowering the `ft_min_word_len` setting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html). You might also want to change or disable the list of ‘stopwords’ (which are also not indexed) whilst you're at it, as the default list is brutal and bizarre.